# Appending object To StructBlock inside StreamField Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wagtail

trying to create new task dynamically in my project on wagtail using **StreamField** and **StructBlock** but without success.

Please help me, I'm losing my mind over this.
The user sets some parameters in the template and then supposed to create a new task...

I tried three different options but this came out.
I have with and without json.dumps
and converting it into a StreamField or StructBlock
Really losing my mind

this is my code:

models.py:

```
tasks = StreamField([
        ("task", blocks.StructBlock([
            ("name", blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=150)),
            ("description", blocks.RichTextBlock(required=False)),
            ("image", ImageChooserBlock(required=False)),
            ("subtasks", blocks.ListBlock(blocks.StructBlock([
                ("name", blocks.CharBlock(required=True, max_length=150)),
                ("description", blocks.RichTextBlock(required=False)),
            ])))
        ]))
    ],null=True,blank=True,use_json_field=True)
```

views:

```
def create_task(request, project_id):
    # create a new task
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)


    # new_task = {
    #     "name": request.POST["task_name"],
    #     "description": str(request.POST["task_description"]),
    #     "image": None,
    #     "subtasks": [],
    # }
    # project.tasks.append(json.dumps(new_task))
#       \Lib\site-packages\wagtail\blocks\stream_block.py", line 610, in _construct_stream_child     
#     type_name, value = item
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
    

    

    # new_task = ('task',{
    #     "name": request.POST["task_name"],
    #     "description": str(request.POST["task_description"]),
    #     "image": None,
    #     "subtasks": [],
    # })
    # project.tasks.append(json.dumps(new_task))
#       \Lib\site-packages\wagtail\blocks\stream_block.py", line 610, in _construct_stream_child     
#     type_name, value = item
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)



    new_task = {
        'type': 'task', 'value': {
            'type': 'name','value': request.POST['task_description'],
            'type': 'description','value': RichText(request.POST['task_description']),
            'type': 'image','value': None,
            'type': 'subtasks','value': [],
        }
    }
    project.tasks.append(json.dumps(new_task))
#         type_name, value = item
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
    
    

    project.save_revision(
        submitted_for_moderation=False,
        approved_go_live_at=None,
        changed=True,
        log_action=True,
        previous_revision=None,
        clean=True,
    ).publish()
    return JsonResponse({"status": "success"})
```

Answer (score 0):

[As mentioned in the StreamField documentation](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/topics/streamfield.html#modifying-streamfield-data), the value to append to the field should be a tuple of `(block_type, value)`. You do not need to JSON-encode it (because then you'll be appending a string, not a tuple).

Additionally, the value of a RichTextBlock should be an instance `wagtail.rich_text.RichText`, rather than a string.

```
from wagtail.rich_text import RichText

new_task = ('task',{
    "name": request.POST["task_name"],
    "description": RichText(request.POST["task_description"]),
    "image": None,
    "subtasks": [],
})
project.tasks.append(new_task)
```

Comment: I got an error:  get_prep_value
    return value.source
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'source'

Comment: @ohadguetta Have updated my answer - the description block needs an additional fix.